# How to configure the BenQ 4k monitor (32 Inch) to work with the Apple Macbook Pro?

Tags: external-display

- While using the Type-C to Type-C cable for connection (BenQ - Macbook) most of the settings were disabled in the monitor.
- The picture mode was only allowing me to choose between HDR and Cinema HDR and no other options such as Low Blue Light, Game were available (greyed-out).
- Additionally, the size of the windows were not scaled abiding by the 32-inch screen upon connecting to it. **For example:** Despite using the Zoom option available in chrome, tab size still remains tiny to view the text in it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I resolved the problems!

1. To resolve the screen Enlargement issue, I have followed the below step.

In the Macbook, System Preferences -> Displays -> Resolution | **Scaled**. It was set to **Default for Display** before and I changed it to **Scaled**.

2. On the same page, System Preferences -> Displays, I have unchecked the **High Dynamic Range** option which in turn enabled all the other settings (color modes).